# How create a dropdown menu in rails without associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My database has a list of games and a junction table for the characters in each game. My question is, how do I show the game list in a drop down, and when the game is selected show the character in another dropdown? I am also trying to make the characters change if another game is selected. I have no associations because I have created all of my relations on the database level. They are all on the database level because I have multiple apps reading from the same database. All the answers that I found have associations being set. How would I accomplish this task with no associations or do I just need to bite the bullet and add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're asking. You'll definitely need associations. A character will need to belong to a game. You can populate the second select box in an `on change` event for the games select box. When a game is selected, trigger an ajax call that populates the other select box with characters from the game. This is basically what you'll need to do.

1. Populate the games select box.

   ```
   f.select(:game_id, options_for_select([["game name", game_id], ["game 2", game_id_2]]))
   ```
2. On change, fire an ajax call to a custom controller action that passes the id of the selected value in the games select box.

   ```
   $(document).on("change", "#game_id_selector", function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "games/get_characters",
         data: {
            game_id: $("#game_id_selector").val()
         }
      }).done(function(ajax_response){
        // append the characters to the other select box using .append()
      })
   })
   ```
3. Have custom controller action and corresponding route ready.

   ```
   resources :games do
      collection do
         post "get_characters"
      end
   end        

   def get_characters
     game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
     characters_arr = []
     game.characters.each {|char| characters_arr << [char.name, char.id] }            
     render json: {data: characters_arr}
   end
   ```
4. Inside controller action, gather all the characters related to that game.
5. Send those back in the json response to the ajax call.
6. Append those characters to the second select box.

That's what you'll need to do, essentially. And you'll need characters to belong to games in order to do it.

Comment: I made all my relations is sql, if send you my database schema will you help me write them?

Comment: it has all the primary keys and foreign keys, I just don't know how to translate them into rails associations.

Comment: you'll want to relate them by writing a migration to add a `game_id` to each `character` record. So you need a `game_id` column on your `characters` table. Then you need to make sure it's properly associating every time you add a character. You should also have a `belongs_to :game` in your character model and a `has_many :characters` in your game model (game.rb)

Comment: I have custom names for all my tables, the combobook and fighting tables are the ones in question. I just need an example using these names. Thanks in advance for helping me. http://pastebin.com/6j8zs3wC

Comment: You might want to decide what your question is and post a new question.

Comment: I set up the associations,  but don't understand what :game_id means in this context, is a model?